# Is there a way to get the all the levels of the parent from the child perspective

Tags: mysql

[here is the sampled table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO1rX.png)

the search filter is only the user

Result result will be the user parents and level

User|Level From Parent

the user is a parent but can also be a child of a parent

User- the parent ID

Level - the level of the child

i need a reverse tree search using only the User to find its all parent..

in short it returns a list of parents. of a single child

somthing like `"Select parent,Level where UserID is child of above parents"`

[sample given data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhrPp.png)

---

i also need help with retrieving its opposite side where the given search filter is the parent and child

parent- the parent is the line of separation of the family tree

partner - based on the parent and child we can retrieve its parter if it has one

something like `"Select Partner where User is a child of parent in the same level of the family tree"`

Comment: provide your table, expected result within your question as a text along with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please make your question clear. And provide your tables, also the result you expect.

Comment: i've updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Materialize path
The Materialized Paths pattern stores each tree node in a document; in addition to the tree node, document stores as a string the id(s) of the node’s ancestors or path. Although the Materialized Paths pattern requires additional steps of working with strings and regular expressions, the pattern also provides more flexibility in working with the path, such as finding nodes by partial paths.